Add equations in math mode to line plot
I have the following plot, that shows two straight lines:
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0, 600, by = 150)
y1 <- 300 + 0.1 * x
y2 <- 450 + 0.2 * x

data <- data.frame(y1, y2)

z <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = y2), color = "blue") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 200, label = "Y_1 = a_1 + 0.1*x = 300 + 0.1*x"), color = "red", hjust = 0, vjust = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 100, label = "Y_2 = a_2 + 0.2*x = 450 + 0.2*x"), color = "blue", hjust = 0, vjust = 1) 
z

What I woud like to have is the equations that I put inside the two labels to be in math mode, ideally latex. So that we can see indices for "Y_1", "Y_2" as well as "a_1" and "a_2". I tried using expressions as shown in some reply, but I always get errors. Is there an easy way to accomplish this that I am missing?

You can achieve your goal with the package latex2exp
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0, 600, by = 150)
y1 <- 300 + 0.1 * x
y2 <- 450 + 0.2 * x

data <- data.frame(y1, y2)
library(latex2exp)
z <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = y2), color = "blue") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 200), label = TeX("$Y_1 = a_1 + 0.1*x = 300 + 0.1*x$"), color = "red", hjust = 0, vjust = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 100), label = TeX("$Y_2 = a_2 + 0.2*x = 450 + 0.2*x$"), color = "blue", hjust = 0, vjust = 1) 
z

